# replacing backslash string in php

Tags: php, mysql, replace, backslash

I need to replace \b with \\b in php in order to insert into mysql table.

Therefore \bhello\b becomes \\bhello\\b then inserted into mysql where it is converted back to \bhello\b.

But I can't seem to figure out how.  Tried preg_replace and str_replace and I always end up with an error or what I started with.

Comment: I am seeing the same as in "I need to replace `x` with `x`", seems the editor ate a few chars?. **edit** seems you corrected it.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you trying to replace a string with the exact same string? A good way to do this is `$result = '\bhello\b';`. Magic.

Comment: fixed it ... replace backslash b with backslash backslash b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the correct escaping mechanism for your database.

For the record, this is [**definitely not `addslashes()`**](http://sadtrombone.com/).

If using [`mysql_*()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), then use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

If using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), use [bound parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with prepared statements.